# Is there any difference between `{m}` and `{m}?` quantifiers?

Tags: regex, quantifiers

Please give an example where the difference between greedy and lazy versions of "repeat-exactly-m-times" quantifier can be seen.
The question arose from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx#sectionToggle10) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).
If there are no differences then what for the `{m}?` quantifier exists?

Comment: @pst: I just tried it in [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/787QjO2MOe), and you seem to be right: it's parsed as 0-or-m (i.e. `?` in `{m}?` is the optionality quantifier, not greediness modifier). Not sure why you deleted your comment, it was spot-on.

Comment: @Amadan - Might that be specific to rubular?  AFAIK, other regex engines treat them identically

Comment: @TheSmose: It can't be specific to Rubular. It may be specific to Oniguruma (the regex engine new Ruby uses). You're right too - JS and Perl, and even old Ruby seem to think differently than Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comments, Oniguruma regexp engine treats it differently, as an exception: `{m}?` is not a non-greedy exact m (which is same as greedy exact m), but 0-or-m. All the other engines I tried did as other posters say: it makes no difference.

The reason for the non-greedy exact m to exist: if it didn't, it's an exception. Exceptions are harder to remember, and harder to implement - it's extra work, and in this case, as the semantics is equal, it doesn't hurt anyone.

I love Oniguruma, and appreciate they might have wanted to change the unneeded bit into something more usable and efficient, but this looks like a bug waiting to happen. Fortunately, no-one sane writes non-greedy exact m...

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is any real difference between `{m}` and `{m}?` since each specifies exactly m times.  However, there is a difference between `{m,}` and `{m,}?` (and `{m,}+`, while we're at it).  It's appropriate and needed for quantifiers in general, even if it isn't needed for that particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't make a difference in exact match `{m}`.

However, will make a difference with `{m,}` as greedy qualifiers match as many characters as possible, whereas lazy qualifiers match as few as possible.

---

Given the string `"Baaaaaaaaaaaa"`

The regex `(B[a]{2,}?)` would match `"Baa"`

The regex `(B[a]{2,})` would match `"Baaaaaaaaaaaa"`

---

Whereas, with the exact match `{m}`:

The regex `(B[a]{2}?)` would match `"Baa"`

The regex `(B[a]{2})` would also match `"Baa"`

Comment: Please give an example where `{2}` and `{2}?` acts differently.

Comment: OP did not ask about `{m,}`.

Comment: AFAIK, {m,} is the only place where it makes a difference??

Comment: And again, OP asked specifically about the comma-less `{m}`.